# Python - If a "good" word and a "bad" word contains in a letter, print it out

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have a Bad word of list and a Good word to list. My idea was to make a first search for Good words and see which meaning in a letter contains those good word but if that meaning also contains a bad word - then it shouldn't print out the meaning.

etc:

```
Good word: "Lo", "Yes"
Bad word: "Hate", "Not"
text_roman: "Hello guys. My name is Lo and I hate to code :')"
```

Meaning: "Hello guys. My name is Lo and I hate to code :')" <-- "*Just a joke!!*

So meaning if it search for that meaning it should tell us there is a meaning that contains good and then check if it contains Bad word. If it does then we don't want to print out the meaning but if it doesn't contain any bad word then we should print it out.

How I tried to code was:

```
text_roman = "Hello guys. My name is Lo and I hate to code :')"
good_word = ["Lo", "Yes"]
bad_word = ["Hate", "Not"]
for text in good_word:
   if text in text_roman:
      print("Yay found word " + text_roman)
      for bad_text in bad_word:
         if bad_text not in text_roman:
             print("Yay no bad words!")
```

When I tried this, the output gave all the words that contains the bad words aswell unfortunately

Comment: What are `text`, `bad_text`, and `text_roman`? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 - Basically it something I just named in those two for loop that are in the code same goes for text and bad_text. text_roman is just a text of meanings but I just added ['meaning'] to let you know that there is a meaning inside the text_roman :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include those values

Comment: @cricket_007 There we go! Now it should work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop over the bad words first, and skip them. Then, if not skipped, check for a good word

```
good_word = ["Lo", "Yes"]
bad_word = ["Hate", "Not"]

has_bad = False
for b in bad_word:
   if b in text_roman:
       has_bad = True 
       continue
   for g in good_word:
      if g in text_roman:
          print("Yay found word " + g + " in text_roman")
if not has_bad:
    print("Yay no bad words!")
```

Note: `in` is case sensitive, so `"Hate" in "I hate case-sensitivity"` will be False

Comment: Hmm, the problem for me right now is - if I want to continue and upgrade this code and by having alot of text meanings - it gonna print out all meanings even thought if its not inside the good_word - meaning what I want to do is that it must contains inside the good_word for it to print out.

Comment: Oh what I did was that I added `has_good =false` and at the last `if not has_bad and has_good` and it will work as I wanted :)

Comment: It still isn't clear where "meaning" is being added to your code, since it's just text, not the definition of an English "meaning"

Comment: Oh lord! I translated in my head. It supposed to say sentence instead of Meaning.

Comment: I would regard the case sensitivity of this program a problem as it won't work with the sample inputs. (It only needs minor adjustemnt, though, so maybe OP is up to that.)

Comment: @usr2564301 Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere: what cricket_007 says in the last line. I mean that there is a chance that you can adjust the code by yourself to make it work for you – case *in*sensitive.

Comment: Oh yeah! Exactly! now I got it as I wished :)